# Iterate Through HiddenFields with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, hiddenfield

How can I iterate through each of these hidden fields and change each one's value with JQuery?

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="field1" runat="server"/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="field2" runat="server"/>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="field3" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by combining `:hidden` selector and `attribute starts with` selector,

```
$(":hidden[id^=field]").val(function(_,val){
 return "anyValueYouWant";
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cvvnakop/)

To make sure that the ID not change use also the `ClientIDMode="Static"` on each control. The ID can change if you place that code on any page that use any master page, or is inside any custom control. So your control must be:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="field1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="field2" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="field3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: your answer is correct, but on asp.net the fields change the id on the final render page and usually the field name go on the end.

Comment: @Aristos Oh I see. I don't know about asp.net. How could we answer it? Would it be helpful if we ask the rendered html from OP?

Comment: I can improve your answer... give me some moments